# how can i configure out the specific project on GCP console?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm figured out the project is visible on gcloud via cl.
I did check by using the following...

```
$ gcloud config list

[core]
account = hogehoge@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = hogehoge_project

Your active configuration is: [hogehoge_project]
```

But the project is not shown on GCP console...
I did log in same gcp account both gcp console and gcloug cl.

please advise what i should check it out...
i am going to configure the project setting.

Comment: Is `gcloud projects list` gives this project?

Answer (score 2):

`hogehoge_project` is an invalid project ID. `_` are not permitted.

Here is the requirement: They must start with a lowercase letter and can have lowercase ASCII letters, digits or hyphens. Project IDs must be between 6 and 30 characters.

It's unclear how this value was set in the configuration but it's not valid and it can't match a GCP project.

I recommend you `gcloud config unset project` to remove the setting and follow @nurgasemetey advice to `gcloud project list` to enumerate all the projects that are available to `hogehoge@gmail.com`.